# question regarding integers and floats in regex

Tags: python-3.x

So I am able to develop the code to extract the float from a string but not able to extract the number from the string.

Here is the string
string = "I like float 33.0; I don't like any other digit but for 3.\n"

```
import re
re.findall('\d\d\D\d',s3)
```

This gives me `['33.0']`
But it does not give 3

I want it so that it spits out `['33.0,'3']` (that is, one set of parenthesis, separated by comma; NOT two sets of parenthetical for each)
I do not want just 33, 3 or 33.0 and 3.0 or any variation thereof. Just as I lay it out.

Comment: The symbol for something that might or might not be there is ?

Comment: Just what I said.

Comment: It is relevant if you wish to write a RegEx that captures both numbers. I believed that was the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty clear that you're asking for projection down to 1st element.

```
import re


def first(xs):
    return xs[0]


def findall1(regex, s):
    return list(map(first, re.findall(regex, s)))


string = "I like float 33.0; I don't like any other digit but for 3.\n"

print(findall1(r'(\d+(\.\d+)?)', string))
```

Result is:

```
['33.0', '3']
```

Comment: this works great but is there any way to do it more efficiently without the defining of functions